# Extension method not available in calling class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, extension-methods

I'm trying to reference an extension method from one class but am getting the following error: "Error: UIColor does not contain a definition for 'FromHex'". My setup is below. I've added an arrow at the beginning of the line where my error is originating from (arrow is not part of my code).

I have an Alert class:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using System.Linq;
using MyApp.iOS;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MyApp.iOS.Alert))]
namespace MyApp.iOS {

    public class Alert : IAlert {
        public void ShowAlert(string title, string message, string button) {
            ShowAlert(title, message, button, null);
        }

        public void ShowAlert(string title, string message, string button, string hexColor) {
            var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(button, UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

            if (hexColor != null) {
                UIView firstSubView = okAlertController.View.Subviews.First();
                UIView alertContentView = firstSubView.Subviews.First();
                foreach (UIView subSubView in alertContentView.Subviews) {
                    --> subSubView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromHex(hexColor); // This line is where I'm getting the error
                }

                okAlertController.View.TintColor = UIColor.Black;
            }

            var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
            var viewController = window.RootViewController;
            while (viewController.PresentedViewController != null) viewController = viewController.PresentedViewController;

            var navigationController = viewController as UINavigationController;
            if (navigationController != null) viewController = navigationController.ViewControllers.Last();

            viewController.PresentViewController(okAlertController, true, null);
        }
    }

}
```

And I have a UIColorExtensions class:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using UIKit;

namespace MyApp.iOS {

    public static class UIColorExtensions {
        public static UIColor FromHex(this UIColor color, string hex) {
            float a = 255, r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;

            if (hex.StartsWith("#")) {
                string hexColor = hex.Substring(1);

                if (hexColor.Length == 8) {
                    float.TryParse(hexColor.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out a);
                    hexColor = hexColor.Substring(2, 6);
                }

                if (hexColor.Length == 6) {
                    float.TryParse(hexColor.Substring(2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out r);
                    float.TryParse(hexColor.Substring(4, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out g);
                    float.TryParse(hexColor.Substring(6, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out b);
                }

                return UIColor.FromRGBA(r, g, b, a);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I can't figure out what I could be doing wrong.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Restarting the IDE
2. Cleaning, rebuilding
3. Getting rid of the assembly line above the namespace line in my Alert class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `UIColor` is not an instance of the class so have to either do something like `UIColor.Red.FromHex(hex)` or modify your extension method to handle it another way.